# Windows 10 (domain joined) double user at login screen

Tags: windows-10

We have a windows 10 computer joined to the domain, the first time the user login everything is fine, but then when she lock the workstation and then press CTRL-ALT-DEL to unlock, in the login screen she has the choice between two users:

name, surname

and

domainname\name_s

the user is the same one, same password and she can login with both and she see exactly the same profile, the problem is that if she unlock the computer with the wrong user from the 2 all the network disks are disconnected, so this create a lot of issues with opened files, outlook and so on.

Just to be sure I checked in the local users, but there is nothing, I also checked in the windows 10 accounts app, I see the domain user just once there.
I checked also on the disk, in the c:\users\ and also there I see the user folder just once.

All the other W10 computers in this same domain does not have this issue.

How can I make disappear this duplication?

In internet I found a lot of articles about this, but all related to standalone pc, not joined to a domain, and those solutions does not apply in this case.

thanks

update: 
I noticed clicking the 2 icons for choosing the user present me little bit different options:
Icon1 above, (the one like "domain\name_s"), presents a link "Access options"
Icon2 below, (the one like "Name Surname"), presents a link "Forgot My password"

In addition to this, the icon below ("Name Surname" without domain name) uses a custom image with the company logo.

So both users in the end is the same user from the domain that allow access to the same profile/open session, but it seems like are coming from 2 kinds of user configurations or something like that

Comment: First user is local one it seems. Try to disable it.

Comment: You sai it's the same login, so in 'C:\Users' you can see only one folder with the user's name? And if you change the domain user's password the other user will change automatically? What happens if you remove the computer from domain and rejoin it?

Comment: Since this is the only machine on the domain that has the problem, I would image the machine again, using your current deployment image.

Comment: @Akina as I wrote in the post I checked, there is no local user, just the domain one

Comment: @Ronaldo I'm waiting for the user for testing the password,  I cannot proceed on my own and I would prefer not to rejoin the client to the domain if not really necessary, sure I'll try it as last resource.

Comment: @Ramhound, sure reimaging the machine is an option if I'll not found anything else,  but it's like rebuild your home because you are not able to repair the sink faucet ;)

Comment: *All the other W10 computers in this same domain does not have this issue.* Ever while logging in with the user in question? And what with another domain user on this station? In another words - does the issue is one of account, workstation or their combination?

Comment: @Akina, good point, is what I want to test, unfortunatly I have to wait for the user as she is not in office and I don't know her password, as soon as possible I'll do these tests, thanks

Comment: @Akina finally I had the computer in my hand and the user password. The same user on another pc works correctly. Another user on that pc has the same issue, so surely the issue is with the machine itself. I noticed one important difference between this pc and the other is the windows version. This pc is 1903 the other are 1809, at the moment I didn't find anything else interesting

Comment: Try to understand when this issue occures, what action provoked it. Maybe it is OS update, some software installation, something else? Maybe try to revert to some OS savepoint before...

Comment: @Akina, unfortunately I don't have idea, first because the issue is there since some time now but the user advise me just yesterday, second because there are in place policies for updates and sw deplyment (by sccm) not managed by me directly, so difficult to say... in the uninstall sw panel the last sw installed I see are  teams and onedrive, I don't think they are related to the issue. Then in the updates the last are from end of july.

Comment: @Akina, I've added an update to my post above, I think these could be useful information to understand better the issue